# How to use tensorflow-wavenet

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to use the [tensorflow-wavenet](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet) program for text to speech.

These are the steps:

1. Download Tensorflow
2. Download librosa
3. Install requirements `pip install -r requirements.txt`
4. Download corpus and put into directory named "corpus"
5. Train the machine `python train.py --data_dir=corpus`
6. Generate audio `python generate.py --wav_out_path=generated.wav --samples 16000 model.ckpt-1000`

After doing this, how can I generate a voice read-out of a text file?

Comment: If tensorflow-wavenet can't do anything besides generate gibberish, is there a functional program where I can combine machine learning with speech generation to create realistic voices?

Comment: Of course Deepmind won´t reveal all the magic and so their paper is lacking the description how they did the local conditioning which is necessary for text to speech generation. Also you need trainingdata that is organized in a way that you can use it for local conditioning -> audio in combination with the spoken text... So you will have to fork the repo and do it yourself or wait till some other genius will do it.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [tensorflow-wavenet page](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet/blob/master/README.md#missing-features):

> Currently there is no local conditioning on extra information which would allow context stacks or controlling what speech is generated.

You can find more information about current development of the project by reading the issues on the repository ([local conditioning is a desired feature!](https://github.com/ibab/tensorflow-wavenet/issues/189))

The Wavenet paper compares Wavenet to two TTS baselines, one of which appears to have code for training available online: http://hts.sp.nitech.ac.jp

Comment: If wavenet cannot do text to speech, then how did they make those demos where the voice makes reservations over the phone?

Comment: "Tensorflow-wavenet" as referred to here is an open source project independent from Google. As far as I know Google has not open sourced their Wavenet code.

Answer (score 2):

A recent paper by DeepMind describes one approach to going from text to speech using WaveNet, which I have not tried to implement but which at least states the method they use: they first train one network to predict a spectrogram from text, then train WaveNet to use the same sort of spectrogram as an additional conditional input to produce speech. It's a neat idea, especially since you can train the WaveNet part on some huge database of voice-only data, for which you can extract the spectrogram, and then train the text-to-spectrogram part using a different dataset where you have text.

https://google.github.io/tacotron/publications/tacotron2/index.html has the paper and some example outputs.

There seems to be a bunch of unintuitive engineering around the spectrogram prediction part (no doubt because of the nature of text-to-time learning), but there's some detail in the paper at least. The dataset is proprietary so I've no idea how hard it would be to get any results using other datasets.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may come across this question, there is a new python implementation [ForwardTacotron](https://github.com/as-ideas/ForwardTacotron) that enables text-to-speech readily.